# const vector reference overloading

Tags: c++, constants, overloading

For simplicity just pass part of the code.

```
class A {
public:
std::vector<int> & get(){ return myVector;}
const std::vector<int> & get() const {return myVector;}
private:
   std::vector<int> myVector;
}
```

My question is how to involve overloaded const get method. When I try to create const_iterator and debug code it involves non-const method.
Want to understand how it works I use the following snippets

```
A myA;
myA.get().push_back(1);
for (const auto& v: myA.get()) { } // it involve not const get method
```

or

```
std::vector<int>::const_iterator cit = myA.get().begin()
//it involves not const method
```

or

```
 const std::vector< int > v = myA.get( );
 // involves non-const method
```

or even I create function:

```
int constVector( const std::vector< int > &constVector )
{
   return constVector[0];
}

int b = constVector( myA.get( ) ); // it involves non-const method
```

What is the purpose of overloaded const method if they are not involved.

And what i doing wrong and how i can involve the const method.

Comment: the const method is called *when the reference to A is const*.

Answer (score 8):

Since `myA` is not *itself* `const`, overload resolution will favour the non-`const` overload.

That's life I'm afraid.

If you want the `const` version then you could use `const_cast` at the calling site, or even an implicit cast, to cast the `myA` to a `const` type:

```
const A& myA_const = myA;
```

and use `myA_const` where you want the `const` overload to be called.

Comment: I'm too late for the answer but you may add the MCVE I prepared on [ideone](https://ideone.com/3fmemE).

Comment: @Scheff: Why do you think you're too late? You answer with that link, and I'll upvote. SO works best if there are multiple answers to choose from.

Answer (score 5):

I took the code fragments of the OP and made an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates what [Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2380830/bathsheba) describes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
  public:
    std::vector<int>& get()
    {
      std::cout << "A::get()" << std::endl;
      return myVector;
    }
    const std::vector<int>& get() const
    {
      std::cout << "A::get() const" << std::endl;
      return myVector;
    }

  private:
    std::vector<int> myVector;
};

int main()
{
  A myA;
  myA.get().push_back(1);
  for (const auto& v: myA.get()) { } // it involve not const get method
  // use const reference to instance
  std::cout << "use const reference to instance" << std::endl;
  { const A &myAC = myA;
    for (const auto& v: myAC.get()) { } // it involves const get method
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A::get()
A::get()
use const reference to instance
A::get() const
```

Tested on [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/3fmemE).